# Jquery search strings seperated by comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to search with jquery if text has any of the values entered in textbox separated by commas.

I used the below code. It works fine if filter is like a,b but fails if filter is a, b. it fails in case where there is space after comma. Is there any option to trim and search?

```
var filter = $(this).val().toString().toLowerCase().replace(/,/g, "|")

if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) >= 0) {
    alert('found')
}
```

Comment: can you share test case inputs?

Comment: Just use `.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, "|")` in filter

Comment: jQuery is a DOM traversing and utility library, and not a string processing library. [String.prototype.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) is a pure javascript functionality using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to perform the search.

Comment: Its batter if you can add your code into jsfiddle.

Comment: For the `.text().toLowerCase().search(new RegExp(filter, "i"))` using both the `toLowerCase` and the `i` (ignore case) flag is redundant. You can omit the `.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: @HarshSanghani The question should always be self-contained, it is a nice addition to also add a link to a playground like jsfiddle, but for the given example it is not necessary. And beside that SO also provides a code snippet tool, for both questions and answers.

Comment: @t.niese If you know the answer just place that rather then argue with me...

Comment: @HarshSanghani I added the comment, because there are still many people here asking questions and post **only** a link to jsfiddle or similar without adding the code to the question itself, but this is not desirable. There was already a solution at the time I have added my comments, one as comment and one as answer, so there was no need to add another one, and beside that you didn't do either, so why are you allowed to note something and I'm not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replace()` methods on strings like this:

```
$(this).val().toString().replace(", ", "|").replace(" ,", "|")
```

Or use regular expression replace.

```
$(this).val().toString().replace("/\s*,\s*/g", "|")
```